# How to create a Gmap view that can be filtered?

Tags: input-formats, google-maps

I have a taxonomy vocabulary that has a multiple terms.

I can create a view that shows the location of all terms in a map, but I want to filter these locations by term. I mean the user first chooses which term and then the map only shows the location of this specific term.

I don't know how to set up filter criteria correctly to achieve this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](https://www.drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it (it would be way too long to include a quote of it all here). That project page also includes various screenshots.

Specific to the "filter" part of your question, here is a quote (also from the project page):

> For those using the Commerce module a ready-to-use Order Locations map is provided ([3rd screenshot](https://www.drupal.org/files/styles/grid-3/public/images/View%20Order%20Locations.jpg)). For each order placed at your store it outputs a marker on the map with its location details retrieved by IPGV&M. The view comes with filters to zoom in on country, time frame and order status. Each order location marker, when clicked, reveals in a text balloon details of the order, e.g number, date placed and order status as well as street address.

**Note**: Uploading custom markers should be possible also, similar to what you can see in the [screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/custom%20markers.jpg) in the feature request about [Custom markers](https://www.drupal.org/node/1985952).

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7 ...